# amdgpu: VBIOS did not find boot engine clock value dependency table. Using Memory DPM level 0!

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04

I upgraded from ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS. But I found following error. I couldn't solve this with anything else. How can I avoid this message? Is there any impact on laptop/PC performance for this messages?

```
/dev/sda8: clean, xxx/yyy files, nnn/nnn blocks
[    41.612950] kfd kfd: amdgpu: TOPAZ not supported in kfd.
[    44.010793] amdgpu: VBIOS did not find boot engine clock value dependency table. Using Memory DPM level 0!
```

Comment: What do you mean by "resolve"? Does the system boot?

Comment: @Pilot6, Dear sir, I don't want to  see this message. How can I avoid this disgusting message? Please help me. THANKS!

Comment: I am afraid there is no easy way to remove it. It doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Some people report that updating system BIOS could help.

Comment: I have the same message in the systemd log on the old laptop with AMD TopaZ card. Ubuntu 22.04.1. Kernel 5.15.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could resolve the issue by free up some pace on root `/` partition. There was no more space left.